# Selected Updates in Nested AppSync Schema

Tags: aws-appsync

I am trying to carry out selected upates of individual nested fields with a DynamoDB table which is connected to an AppSync interface. I am able to update individual top level fields but when it comes to nested fields I am unsure how to approach. I am a newbie to this so perhaps I am thinking about this wrong and I need to flatten the data through the schema so that the data is flat in the DynamoDb tables. I have struggled to find an example of how to tackle this kind of situation with fairly complex tables. I am using the Custom Types to bring some standardisation across the App and different resolvers/.
We have a AppSync Schema defined approximately like this

```
type Main_entries {
    id: String!
    title: String!
    recordInfo: CustomType
}

Type CustomType {
fieldA: String
fieldB: String
fieldC: String
}
```

What I have are some main types but also some Custom Types used throughout the application. What I want to be able to do is to update fieldB whilst keeping the rest of the data intact.

I have used the UpdateItem approach [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/tutorial-dynamodb-resolvers.html)
With this I can say update title whilst keeping the rest of the record intact but if my Mutation instructs fieldB to be updated a SET is created to update the entire recordInfo type so fieldA and fieldC are omitted.
Does anyone know of any ideas or even better know where there may be some examples.
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You can attach a resolver on the `recordInfo` field. If you go through the AppSync console and choose `Create with wizard` and `Event App`. This sample will help you out with this use case.

Comment: Thanks - I will have a look at that

Comment: Just ran through the example - Not certain I can see it doing something similar....Although I might not be understanding. The issue is when I am carrying out a mutation that I wish to mutate just one field within the custom type (e.g. FieldB whilst keeping fieldA and fieldC with their current values).

Comment: As an update I nearly manged this. I could use a set of for loops to traverse the map and use statements like #if ($util.isMap($entry.value)) to determine whether I was at a map entry. I would then use this information to ignore creating an entry in the Step request but instead traverse to the next level.

I still had the following problems;
1) If the Map doesn't then it errors. I tried using if_not_exists to create the map before I did the updates but I get a "Two document paths overlap with each other;" error.

Comment: 2) The second issue is that I ideally need to be able to call a procedure to traverse down through the map. I could not find a way to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @IThoughtItWouldBeEasy did you find a solution for this?